# How can I label the graph axes?

Tags: matlab

I have matlab code that plots a graph.

```
x=0:1:6076*25;
w=7.8;
[X,Z] = ode45(@(t,Z) sys(t,Z,w),x,[2000 tand(7.8)]);
plot(X,Z(:,1),'r')  %Z(:,1) is z(x) and Z(:,2) is z'(x).
```

How can I label the axes? I'd like to label both the horizontal and the vertical axes.

[image]

Comment: Minor comment.  This code doesn't work for me.  Get an error when calling `ode45` which says that `sys` can't be called with arguments of type `double`.

Comment: @rayryeng As you've noticed we've overridden the `sys` function to solve the differential equation. We are solving a [numerical methods problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283426/are-my-results-realistic-or-is-there-an-error-somewhere).

Comment: Sounds good.  Interesting problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`xlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlabel.htm) and [`ylabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylabel.html).

After your plot has been spawned, do something like this:

```
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Amplitude');
```

You place in a string for `xlabel` and `ylabel` and it will place labels on either the `x`-axis (`xlabel`) or the `y`-axis (`ylabel`).  Replace `Time` and `Amplitude` with whatever you wish.  Make sure your plot is visible first before you do this, so you can place those statements after your `plot` command.

If you'd like to add a title to your graph, you can also use the [`title`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html) command too:

```
title('My Graph');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xlabel('string');
ylabel('string');
```

'String' is the text you'd like to see displayed.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use title('string') to create a title for the graph