# What does dZ(1)=Z(2) mean in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have the following MATLAB code and I'm wondering what the following means:

```
dZ(1)=Z(2)
```

This is from the following code:

```
function dZ=sys(t,Z,w)

% inline function for c(z)
c=@(z)4800 - 20.2090 + (17.3368)*z/1000+ (272.9057)*exp(-z*0.7528/1000); 
% inline function for c'(z)

dc=@(z) 17.3368/1000 - (272.9057)*(0.7528/1000)*exp(-z*0.7528/1000); 
q=c(2000);
dZ=zeros(2,1);    % a column vector
dZ(1)=Z(2);
dZ(2)=-(q/cosd(w))^2* dc(Z(1))/c(Z(1))^3; 
end
```

Comment: It means make the first element of the matrix `dZ` equal to the second element of matrix `Z`. Note that `Z` is a parameter that is passed in and is different from `z` which is scoped to the single line anonymous function it is declared in

Comment: Pretty much the same as any other language which supports vectorized data.  What's your programming background?

Comment: Since your background supposedly includes Python, think of `dZ` as a list of two elements that was initially given zeroes.  That statement `dZ(1)=Z(2)`, as well as the statement below it, is just assigning each element in `dZ` to some number.

Comment: Minor comment.  I've seen the "`sys`" function used in this way before, overriding what `sys` actually is (from the Control Systems Toolbox): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626605/how-can-i-label-the-graph-axes/30626643.  I commented on this code saying that it doesn't work out of the box, but the OP never commented back.  Do you two work together?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I didn't know that I was overriding a builtin `sys`. We're using it to solve differential equations. I'm a beginner at matlab from a python and Java background.

Comment: @Niklasinstockholm - Not a problem at all :) I was wondering... I remember seeing another question where someone was overriding `sys`, and when I saw it being used in this context here, it clicked... which is why I asked about the previous question.  Good luck with your work!

Comment: @rayryeng I understand it is maybe not a good idea to override a builtin function so I can change the name. There're more questions I asked about the same problem [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19834/is-iteration-an-efficient-algorithm-in-this-case) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283426/are-my-results-realistic-or-is-there-an-error-somewhere) with a link to the mathematical background of the problem which has interesting physical interpretation. We can also use other methods (Euler's) to see if the results are similar or close. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Niklasinstockholm - Thanks! I'll read up on it soon. BTW, thank you for the donation :)

Comment: @rayryeng This assignment was homework that we finally passed and got graded ok. It was good to learn matlab and some physics too.

Comment: I'm very glad. I also got a friendly message from your friend Niklas over on Codementor. Thanks so much and have a happy holiday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dZ is a function, and in line 1, Z is an input into the function.  If this function is mean to do scalar arithmetic, Z is probably a number.  However, the value of Z is equal to Z(1).

In other words, your input into the function Z = Z(1), as a single element array, or Z = Z(1) = [INPUT]

the line dZ(1) = Z(2) then redefines Z to be an array with two elements, instead of the single input. Now, this defines Z to be Z = [INPUT, dZ(1)] instead of Z = [INPUT].

Does that make sense?